# How to create (m) columns and (n) rows for a rectangular pattern using nested for loops in java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I just learned how to use nested loops today and the task I am required to do is quite simple but I am not able to execute it properly, although with the same idea.

The task is to input a **character**, an integer that is the rows**(n)**, and another integer that is the columns **(m)**

It should display the rectangular pattern with **n rows and m columns**

Sample input:

```
*
3
2
```

Here the **number of rows is 3 and the number of columns is 2**

Sample output:

```
**
**
**
```

**This has to be done using nested for loops only**

My code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Example {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String character = keyboard.next();
        int n = keyboard.nextInt();
        int m = keyboard.nextInt();

        for (int x = m; x <= m; x++) {
            for (int y =n ; y <= n; y++) {
                System.out.print(character);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

The output I am getting:

```
*
```

Comment: How is it going wrong, though?Could you show the output you got that was not correct?

Comment: looks like a homework question, try to debug the code yourself and find out the reason.

Comment: @nikoo28 It probably is, but at least the OP tried to solve it

Comment: The issue is with the starting limit on each of the loops it is same as the exit-limit. Typically the start limit is `0` if you are using a `<` operator to compare exit-limit. Sometimes programmers use start-limit as `1`. Then you are forced to use `<=` for comparing exit-limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start from `0` in both loops until reaching `< m` and `< n` as follows:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String character = keyboard.next();
int n = keyboard.nextInt();
int m = keyboard.nextInt();
for (int x = 0; x < m; x++){
    for (int y = 0; y < n; y++){
        System.out.print(character);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

A sample input/output would be:

```
*
3
2
***
***
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use a loop like this start from 0 to row and j from 0 to col for each row, and close the scanner after reading

```
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String character = keyboard.next();
        int col = keyboard.nextInt();
        int row = keyboard.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                System.out.print(character);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        keyboard.close();
    }
```

, output

```
***
***
```

Comment: Variables should be named something meaningful, +1!

Answer (score 0):

what is wrong in your code is that you are starting loop from m itself instead you should think it like how many times you want to run the loop.
With that in mind try running the code from 0 to m and inner loop from 0 to n.
This mindset will help you in learning while loop also.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Example {
public static void main (String[] args) 

{

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String character = keyboard.next();
int n = keyboard.nextInt();
int m = keyboard.nextInt();

for (int x = 0;x<m;x++){
    for (int y=0;y<n;y++){
        System.out.print(character);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
}

}
```